# How does the swap work in Selection sort?

Tags: java

can someone please explain why the swap portion of this method works, I have been using this method for some time but I can't wrap my head around how the swap portion works. I would appreciate it if someone could explain it. thank you

```
      public static int [] selectionSort(int [] num){
       int min=0,minIndex=0;
       for(int i=0; i< num.length-1;i++){
           min=num[i];
       for(int x=i+1;x<num.length;x++){
           if(min > num[x]){
               min=num[x];
               minIndex=x;
           }
       }
      //this is the part Im so confused about 
      if(num[i]> min){
          int temp=num[i];
          num[i]=num[minIndex];
          num[minIndex]=temp;  
       }  
   }
   return num;
   }
```

Comment: What's confusing? It's swapping the element at index `i` with the element at index `minIndex`.

Comment: Try to write the code to swap the values of two variables and you will understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole notion of selection sort is to select the index of the next smallest element and move it to its rightful position.

In every iteration of selection sort, the minimum element (considering ascending order) from the unsorted subarray is picked and moved to the sorted subarray.

The following example explains the above steps:

```
int arr[] = {64, 25, 12, 22, 11}

Find the minimum element in arr[0...4]
    and place it at beginning

            *11* 25 12 22 64

Find the minimum element in arr[1...4]
    and place it at beginning of arr[1...4]

            11 *12* 25 22 64

Find the minimum element in arr[2...4]
    and place it at beginning of arr[2...4]

            11 12 *22* 25 64

Find the minimum element in arr[3...4]
    and place it at beginning of arr[3...4]

            11 12 22 *25* 64 (64 is automatically sorted)
```

At each step, you find `minIndex`. You then swap the value in `arr[minIndex]` with the value in `arr[i]`.

So at iteration `0`, `minIndex` will be `4` since `11` is at index `4`, and `i` is, of course, `0` since it is the first iteration.... and so on.

At iteration 0,
`num[i] => 64`, and `num[maxIndex] => 11`.

```
int temp = num[i]; // temp => 64
num[i] = num[minIndex]; // num[i] = num[minIndex] => 11
num[minIndex] = temp;   // num[minIndex] => 64
```

After iteration 0,
`num[i] => 11`, and `num[maxIndex] => 64`.

Comment: your step by step explanation was the missing link for me, thank your for your help

Comment: @Msinger Glad I was able to help. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Since variables in Java aren´t adressed with pointers but with their value (call-of value instead call-of reference), you need to assign a temp variable to store your smallest value in. Because you are setting the num[i] to another number, you need to be able to access the number later.

```
int temp=num[i]; //create temp variable to store the number in array num on index i
num[i]=num[minIndex]; // assign a new number to num on index i 
num[minIndex]=temp;  // now assign the temp number to num on index minIndex
```